# How to get a valid DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, ldap

I am trying to read an LDAP directory entry in a C# console application and I somehow don't succeed. Setting up the connection works fine:

```
private static LdapConnection ldapConnection;

public static void Main()
{
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("uid=admin,ou=system", "secret");
    ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("127.0.0.1:10389");
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

    try
    {
        ldapConnection.Bind(credentials);
        Console.WriteLine("Ldap connection is created.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nUnexpected exception occurred:\r\n\t" + e.GetType() + ":" + e.Message);
        return;
    }

    //searchUsers();
    //getSchemaClassName();
}
```

I can even find me some users:

```
private static void searchUsers()
{
    string[] attrs = new string[] { "cn", "sn" };
    string[] followedBy = new string[] { " ", "\n" };
    var request = new SearchRequest("ou=users,ou=system", "(objectClass=*)", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, attrs);
    var response = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(request);

    foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < attrs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (entry.Attributes.Contains(attrs[i]))
            {
                Console.Write(entry.Attributes[attrs[i]].GetValues(Type.GetType("System.String"))[0] + followedBy[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I for example try to read a directory entry's schema classname, I find that the directory entry contains a bunch of errors. This is the code:

```
private static void getSchemaClassName()
{
    string path = "ldap://localhost:10389/cn=David,ou=users,ou=system"; //path is ok, points to an existing user
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, "uid=admin,ou=system", "secret");
    Console.WriteLine("Schema classname:" + de.SchemaClassName); //breakpoint here
}
```

When I place a breakpoint on the "breakpoint here"-line and subsequently examine `de` properties, I find that `Guid`, `Name`, `Options`, `Parent`, `SchemaClassName` and some others display the "The directory service is unavailable" error. Which even makes sense to me, since `ldapConnection` isn't in any way involved in this code, whereas it is in `searchUsers()`. But I don't know how to connect this code to `ldapConnection`; every DirectoryEntry example I come across on the internet apparently works without the connection. How can I get this fixed?

Thx, Cooz

**Edit:**

Changing `getSchemaClassName()` to the following helped somewhat...

```
private static void getSchemaClassName()
{
    string path = "LDAP://localhost:10389/cn=David,ou=users,ou=system";
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, "uid=admin,ou=system", "secret", AuthenticationTypes.None);
    Console.WriteLine("Schema classname:" + de.SchemaClassName); //breakpoint here
}
```

...but not enough. Now at first sight only the `Guid` and `NativeGuid` properties of `de` give a *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException* and the rest seems fine. `de.SchemaClassName` is "organizationalPerson". Perfect.

However, upon setting the breakpoint once again and expanding for example `de.SchemaEntry.SchemaEntry`, almost everything that becomes visible there throws said exception: `Guid`, `Name`, `ObjectSecurity`, `Options`, `SchemaClassName`, `SchemaEntry`... you name it. The code still is not much use to me. What might be the possible cause of all those errors and how can I get it fixed?

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember I had to use CAPITAL prefixes on my LDAP paths - have you tried using `LDAP://localhost:10389/cn=David,ou=users,ou=system` - any difference?

Comment: @marc_s Yes, I tried that. No difference.

Comment: I think this is because DirectoryEntry.username parameter expects a _full_ distinguished name (or an NT account domain\user, or user principal user@domain), instead of just "uid=admin,ou=system".

Comment: @marc_s I have edited my question, and this time changing "ldap" to "LDAP" did make a difference - but not enough, as you can see.
I noticed that your name frequently pops up at LDAP related questions... do you perhaps have any other ideas?

Comment: @EricLavault Yes, you are probably right - in other examples that I find, the domain is indeed added to the username. I'm only not quite sure what that would be in my case - something like _"localhost:10389\\uid=admin,ou=system"_ perhaps?
I've tried several variations, but to no avail yet.

Comment: @Cooz `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` classes are specifically designed to work with ADSI (meaning it's Active Directory-specific). It's unlikely you're gonna make it work meaningfully with any other LDAP server. Rewrite your `getSchemaClassName` method to carry out a `SearchRequest()` instead. Set search scope to `Base` and the base DN to the DN of the target object, eg. `new SearchRequest("cn=David,ou=users,ou=system", "(objectClass=*)", SearchScope.Base, new string[] { "nameOfSchemaClassNameAttributeForYourSpecificLDAPImplementation" });`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Goodness me... well, that explains _quite_ a lot. I finally see the light - <facepalm here>. Thank you Mathias.